# d3.js - attribute d: Expected number

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following segment in one of my d3 codes. It throws an error saying

attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,185697.89LNa…".

```
            var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
               .x(function (d) {
                   return d.date;
               })
               .y(function (d) {
                   return d.close;
               })
               .interpolate("basis");

           var pth = g.append('svg:path')
               .attr('d', lineGen(data))
               .attr('stroke', '#000')
               .attr('stroke-width', 3.5)
               .attr('fill', 'none');
```

In the intellisense, it does not even show "date" and "close" for "d".
Given below is the data set I'm passing to the function.
I think it does not access the "data" array and that is why it says it is empty. And, wondering how it can be empty when I've already passed it to the method.

```
 var data = [{ "date": "2016.07.19", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": 
"2016.07.20", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.21", "close": 
186601.1 }, { "date": "2016.07.22", "close": 187273.89 }, { "date": 
"2016.07.25", "close": 186807.74 }, { "date": "2016.07.26", "close": 
186893.26 }...]
```

Please help me to locate the error and to see where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert string date (ex. '2016.07.19') to JavaScript date object.

I created graph from your data, look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/65otj2sL/1/

Please note the following:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse;
...

var data = [
  { "date": "2016.07.19", "close": 185697.89 },
  { "date": "2016.07.20", "close": 185697.89 },
  { "date": "2016.07.21", "close": 186601.1 },
  { "date": "2016.07.22", "close": 187273.89 },
  { "date": "2016.07.25", "close": 186807.74 },
  { "date": "2016.07.26", "close": 186893.26 }
];

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});
```

Comment: Note: in your case, you should use another format specifier - `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse`;

Comment: Hi ! It's still the same. still throws the same error

Comment: @Nishi I created chart from your data and updated the answer. Look at the new fiddle.

Comment: Can you pls look in to the fiddle I've posted ?. That'd be of great help. pls

Comment: but if you debug the code, you see that there is this error thrown. attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,185697.89LNa…". . Graph drawing is completed before that point. This error is related to the tooltip generation part

Comment: tooltip should be visible if the error is fixed :( I know you put a lot of effort. Can you pls see why the tooltip is not visible ?

Comment: @Nishi I suppose, that is another question. You got `undefined` for `d0` in `hoverMouseOn` function as result tooltip not showing.